# mongodb remove document that match each element in array

Tags: python, mongodb

mongodb

```
{'id':'a'}
{'id':'b'}
{'id':'c'}
{'id':'d'}
......
```

python

```
pool = ['a','b','c']
for element in pool:
    mongodb.remove({'id':element})
```

Just like such situation.
I have a list, as id list.
And I want to remove each one from mongodb.

is there any method better than do it one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.remove({'_id':{'$in': pool}})
```

This will remove all the records at one go.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete the whole document:

The `.remove()` method takes a query object, you could use regular expressions with it :

```
db.collection.remove({ "id": /your_regex/})
```

will remove every document  that match your regular expression.

If you want to remove a specific field you should use the [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) attribute just like this:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$unset: {"field":1}}, {multi: true})
```